# css cubic-bezier javascript function

Tags: javascript

Я пишу функцию анимации и сейчас пытаюсь реализовать cubic-bezier как в css. Использую формулу для 4-ёх точек вот [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/bezier#%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

У меня получилась вот таккая фукция:

```
function cubicBezier(p, t){
   var y = 1 - t;

   return ((0 * Math.pow(y, 3)) + (p[0] * t * Math.pow(y, 2)) + (p[1] * Math.pow(t, 2) * y) + (1 * Math.pow(t, 3)));
}
```

где t - [0,1]

[Вот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEtrd.jpg) что он рисует.

[image]

Вот код который рисует:

```
var p = [.5, 0, .5, 1];

        var ctx = cubic.getContext('2d');

        function cubicBezier(p, t){
            var y = 1 - t;

            return ((0 * Math.pow(y, 3)) + (p[0] * t * Math.pow(y, 2)) + (p[1] * Math.pow(t, 2) * y) + (1 * Math.pow(t, 3)));

        }

        cubic.width = cubic.offsetWidth;
        cubic.height = cubic.offsetHeight;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#F44336";



        function X(i){
            return i * 400 + 50;
        }

        ctx.moveTo(50, 50);

        ctx.lineTo(X(p[0]),X(p[1]));
        ctx.lineTo(X(p[2]),X(p[3]));
        ctx.lineTo(X(1),X(1));

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#4CAF50";
        ctx.moveTo(50, 50);

        for(var t = 0; t<1; t = t + .01){
            ctx.lineTo(X(cubicBezier([p[0], p[1]], t)), X(cubicBezier([p[2], p[3]], t)));
        }

        ctx.stroke();
```

Поскажите пожалуйста правельную формулу для вычесления.

P.s. В гугле на эту тему от силы статей 5 и все на английском, я мало что понял там(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плохо ищите, первые же результаты поиска:

- [готовая библиотека](https://github.com/arian/cubic-bezier)
- [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696736/recreating-css3-transitions-cubic-bezier-curve)
- [еще одно решение](https://gist.github.com/mckamey/3783009)

Если плохо знаете английский, то просто читайте код, обычно и так все понятно.

Непосредственно функция, взятая из 3 пункта:

```
/**
 * Defines a cubic-bezier curve given the middle two control points.
 * NOTE: first and last control points are implicitly (0,0) and (1,1).
 * @param p1x {number} X component of control point 1
 * @param p1y {number} Y component of control point 1
 * @param p2x {number} X component of control point 2
 * @param p2y {number} Y component of control point 2
 */
var unitBezier = function(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y) {

    // private members --------------------------------------------

    // Calculate the polynomial coefficients, implicit first and last control points are (0,0) and (1,1).

    /**
     * X component of Bezier coefficient C
     * @const
     * @type {number}
     */
    var cx = 3.0 * p1x;

    /**
     * X component of Bezier coefficient B
     * @const
     * @type {number}
     */
    var bx = 3.0 * (p2x - p1x) - cx;

    /**
     * X component of Bezier coefficient A
     * @const
     * @type {number}
     */
    var ax = 1.0 - cx -bx;

    /**
     * Y component of Bezier coefficient C
     * @const
     * @type {number}
     */
    var cy = 3.0 * p1y;

    /**
     * Y component of Bezier coefficient B
     * @const
     * @type {number}
     */
    var by = 3.0 * (p2y - p1y) - cy;

    /**
     * Y component of Bezier coefficient A
     * @const
     * @type {number}
     */
    var ay = 1.0 - cy - by;

    /**
     * @param t {number} parametric timing value
     * @return {number}
     */
    var sampleCurveX = function(t) {
        // `ax t^3 + bx t^2 + cx t' expanded using Horner's rule.
        return ((ax * t + bx) * t + cx) * t;
    };

    /**
     * @param t {number} parametric timing value
     * @return {number}
     */
    var sampleCurveY = function(t) {
        return ((ay * t + by) * t + cy) * t;
    };

    /**
     * @param t {number} parametric timing value
     * @return {number}
     */
    var sampleCurveDerivativeX = function(t) {
        return (3.0 * ax * t + 2.0 * bx) * t + cx;
    };

    /**
     * Given an x value, find a parametric value it came from.
     * @param x {number} value of x along the bezier curve, 0.0 <= x <= 1.0
     * @param epsilon {number} accuracy limit of t for the given x
     * @return {number} the t value corresponding to x
     */
    var solveCurveX = function(x, epsilon) {
        var t0;
        var t1;
        var t2;
        var x2;
        var d2;
        var i;

        // First try a few iterations of Newton's method -- normally very fast.
        for (t2 = x, i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            x2 = sampleCurveX(t2) - x;
            if (Math.abs (x2) < epsilon) {
                return t2;
            }
            d2 = sampleCurveDerivativeX(t2);
            if (Math.abs(d2) < 1e-6) {
                break;
            }
            t2 = t2 - x2 / d2;
        }

        // Fall back to the bisection method for reliability.
        t0 = 0.0;
        t1 = 1.0;
        t2 = x;

        if (t2 < t0) {
            return t0;
        }
        if (t2 > t1) {
            return t1;
        }

        while (t0 < t1) {
            x2 = sampleCurveX(t2);
            if (Math.abs(x2 - x) < epsilon) {
                return t2;
            }
            if (x > x2) {
                t0 = t2;
            } else {
                t1 = t2;
            }
            t2 = (t1 - t0) * 0.5 + t0;
        }

        // Failure.
        return t2;
    };

    /**
     * @param x {number} the value of x along the bezier curve, 0.0 <= x <= 1.0
     * @param epsilon {number} the accuracy of t for the given x
     * @return {number} the y value along the bezier curve
     */
    var solve = function(x, epsilon) {
        return sampleCurveY(solveCurveX(x, epsilon));
    };

    // public interface --------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Find the y of the cubic-bezier for a given x with accuracy determined by the animation duration.
     * @param x {number} the value of x along the bezier curve, 0.0 <= x <= 1.0
     * @param duration {number} the duration of the animation in milliseconds
     * @return {number} the y value along the bezier curve
     */
    return function(x, duration) {
        return solve(x, solveEpsilon(+duration || DEFAULT_DURATION));
    };
};
```

Comment: Всё это я видел, спецально для вас и написал "в гугле на эту тему от силы статей 5 и все на английском, я мало что понял там", и дело не только в английском. Вы сами то смотрели код ? Поняли как они получают кординаты ? Если да, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: а в чем проблема использовать готовую библиотеку?

Comment: Вы пробовали сделать больший шаг? И не очень понятно почему `return ((0 * Math.pow(y, 3)) + (p[0] * t * Math.pow(y, 2)) + (p[1] * Math.pow(t, 2) * y) + (1 * Math.pow(t, 3)));` - здесь все члены не домножаются на p[i], а первый и последний умножены на 0 и 1. В умножении на 0 точно нет смысла, тогда зачем вообще указывать этот член.
Насколько я понимаю по формуле из вашей ссылки, координата каждой точки вычисляется по всем p[i] и t, а вы пытаетесь соединить две функции cubic bezier `ctx.lineTo(X(cubicBezier([p[0], p[1]], t)), X(cubicBezier([p[2], p[3]], t)));`

Comment: Т.е. на скорее всего должно быть так `return ((p[0] * Math.pow(y, 3)) + (p[1] * t * Math.pow(y, 2)) + (p[2] * Math.pow(t, 2) * y) + (p[3] * Math.pow(t, 3)));` и так `ctx.lineTo(X(cubicBezier(p, t)), X(cubicBezier(p, (t + 0.1))));`